# Main Bundle of an SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Sorry that you wont find any code as this is more of a theoretical question.

I have created an iOS app and inserted an SDK project into it. That SDK holds a few files which I need to reach but I cant see them using [NSBundle mainBundle].

How do I reach files that are in a subproject of my main project?

Comment: How did you add the SDK??

Comment: Dragged the project into my project and added the framework into the "Link Binary With Libraries" in Build Phases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files in your SDK are classes or interfaces then import the whole SDK in the class you want to use them like - `#import <mySDK/mySDK.h>` something like this, xcode will auto complete for you.|

If it is some file then importing them and calling the file by its URL from your mailBundle, here as your SDK is inside your bundle, you will be able to access it. But you need to know the name of the file from beforehand, or you can see that by just navigating inside the SDK bundle from your navigator.